# universal inbox app to show all the incoming messages from different chat apps

Tags: android, whatsapp, skype, messenger, viber

I am developing a universal inbox app to show all the incoming messages from different chat apps like WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, WeChat, QQ, SMS, Viber, Skype etc. Can you please tell me if there are any common APIs to integrate these apps with my app. How can I read the WhatsApp and Facebook messages and display them in my app?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with developing a universal inbox or common inbox app is that there are no common APIs that work for all chat apps. However, there are some interesting workarounds that we have used for OneApp.

Have a look at OneApp. It is a universal inbox developed using the notifications. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.justoneapp.  It does some cool things including providing a timeline and conversation view. It also works for most of the chat apps available today in the market. Please let me know if you need any further information.